# Dúvida - Query SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Tenho uma consulta abaixo que preciso trazer dentro do case somente quando o campo TarVencimento for menor que a data de hoje (até aqui consegui fazer), porém, somente quando a data de hoje seja até o 5° dia posterior a data do vencimento.
Exemplo: Uma tarefa de número 11111 foi vencida dia 10/11/2017 e hoje é 22/11/2017 sendo assim, não era para trazer essa tarefa, era para trazer somente se data de hoje fosse do dia 11/11 até 15/11.

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN  T.TarVencimento < getdate() THEN CAST(datediff(day,TarVencimento,getdate()) AS VARCHAR) ELSE '0' END +' (TEMPO)'
    FROM Tarefa T
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veja se é isso

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN dateadd(day, 5, T.TarVencimento) < getdate() THEN  
         CAST(datediff(day, TarVencimento, getdate()) AS VARCHAR) 
    ELSE '0' END +' (TEMPO)'
FROM Tarefa T
```

Comment: Dessa forma nao deu certo @Will Palaro.

Comment: O que pega? Deu erro? Tá trazendo dia a mais ou a menos?